# Actualizar gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Buenas, quisiera que me puedan ayudar tengo un `GridView` como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando selecciono en `Ver` me muestra  un *popup* o una ventana emergente como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que cuando presiono en `Guardar` sí se graba correctamente y sale un mensaje se registró correctamente como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando se cierra se muestra nuevamente el `GridView` pero en el campo donde dice validado tiene que decir SÍ y no se actualiza el gridview.

Este es el código que utilizo para grabar:

```
   protected void BtnnoConforme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox11.Text);
            string mes = d1.ToString("MM");
            string anio = d1.ToString("yyyy");


            DateTime d3 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
            string FechaPagoMes = d3.ToString("MM");
            string FechaPagoAnio = d3.ToString("yyyy");
            if (mes != FechaPagoMes)
            {
                Label1.Text = "El Mes y año de la Fecha de Vencimiento de Recibo tiene que ser igual al Mes y Año de Fecha de Cumplimiento   :     " + TextBox11.Text;
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (anio != FechaPagoAnio)
            {
                Label1.Text = "El Mes y año de la Fecha de Vencimiento de Recibo tiene que ser igual al Mes y Año de Fecha de Cumplimiento   :     " + TextBox11.Text;
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (mes != FechaPagoMes)
            {
                Label1.Text = "El Mes de Pago tiene que ser del Mismo Mes Actual";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);


            }
            else if (anio != FechaPagoAnio)
            {
                Label1.Text = "El Año  Tiene que ser igual al Año de Actual";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (TextBox4.Text == "")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Ingresa Su Fecha de Emision";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);


            }
            else if (DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text) > DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text))
            {
                Label1.Text = "La Fecha de Emision tiene que ser Menor a la Fecha Vencimiento";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (TextBox4.Text == "")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Ingresa Su Fecha de Emision";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (TextBox6.Text == "")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Ingrese el Monto";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (TextBox6.Text == "0.0")
            {
                Label1.Text = "El monto debe ser mayor de 0";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (TextBox6.Text == "0")
            {
                Label1.Text = "El monto debe ser mayor de 0";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);


            }


            else if (TextBox4.Text == "")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Ingresa Su Fecha de Emision";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else if (TextBox6.Text == "..")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Ingresa Su Fecha de Emision";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }



            else if (TextBox11.Text == "")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Ingresa Su Fecha de Emision";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);

            }
            else
            {

                string fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

                int fileLength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;



                byte[] imageBytes = new byte[fileLength];

                FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, fileLength);


                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_atendertarea", cn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@idregistrotarea", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechaemision", SqlDbType.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechacumplimiento", SqlDbType.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechaatendido", SqlDbType.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@montopagado", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@numerorecibo", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@tarea", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@oficina", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechaemisions", SqlDbType.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@comentario", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechacumplimientotarea", SqlDbType.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fileContent", SqlDbType.Image);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ERROR", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@registro", SqlDbType.Int);



                cmd.Parameters["@idregistrotarea"].Value = lblidregistrotareas.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@usuario"].Value = TextBox3.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@fechaemision"].Value = TextBox4.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@fechacumplimiento"].Value = TextBox5.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@fechaatendido"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@montopagado"].Value = TextBox6.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@numerorecibo"].Value = TextBox7.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@tarea"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@oficina"].Value = TextBox10.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@fechaemisions"].Value = TextBox4.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@comentario"].Value = "";
                cmd.Parameters["@fechacumplimientotarea"].Value = TextBox11.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@fileName"].Value = fileName;
                cmd.Parameters["@fileContent"].Value = imageBytes;
                cmd.Parameters["@active"].Value = true;
                cmd.Parameters["@registro"].Value = true;


                cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                cn.Open();

                BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;

                Label1.Text = message;


                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal1();", true);
                /*INICIO */

                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SP_SeguimientoTareaMaster", con);


                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("OPT", 1);


                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);



                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    DtgSolicitudes.DataSource = dt;
                    DtgSolicitudes.Visible = true;


                    DtgSolicitudes.DataBind();

                    if (DtgSolicitudes.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {

                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[9].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[10].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[11].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[12].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[13].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[14].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.Cells[15].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
                        DtgSolicitudes.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;




                        con.Close();

                    }
                }

                /* FIN */

                cn.Close();

                TextBox6.Text = "";


            }

        }
```

Si me podrían ayudar.

Comment: Hola Pierro, edité tu pregunta y eliminé las partes de código comentadas así como los espacios en blanco. Como recomendación te diría que en lugar de tener múltiples `else-if` lo ideal sería tener un `case-switch` ya que de esta forma solo se evalúa una condición y con el código actual se evalúan todas las condiciones posibles :)

Comment: @Flxtr muchas gracias por la recomendacion la verdad no sabia pero genial excelente :D

Comment: nunca estas refrescando la grilla al volver de los pop-ups no? me perdi en la maraña de codigo...

Comment: no por eso es la pregunta amigo @gbianchi

Comment: @gbianchi amigo por eso es que pregunto como refrescar la grilla

Comment: ok, volvamos atras. agrega como cargas la grilla originalmente..

Comment: amigo e mi codigo esta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi llegas a la respuesta, es correcto en querer volver a cargar nuevamente los datos y llenar el *grid*, solo existen varios puntos que se deben corregir:

- No es necesario poner `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`
- Declaras `cmd1` con `SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SP_SeguimientoTareaMaster", con);` pero cuando agregas el parámetro lo haces a la variable `cmd` la cual habías declarado anteriormente
- Cuando declaras el `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);` lo relacionas con `cmd1`, el cual no lleva parámetros para la ejecución del *stored procedure*

Tu código deberá quedar algo así:

```
//Aquí va todo el código anterior, no considero necesario ponerlo
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
conexion.Open();

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SP_SeguimientoTareaMaster", conexion);

sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("OPT", 1);

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DtgSolicitudes.DataSource = dt;
DtgSolicitudes.Visible = true;
//Aquí va el código con el que finaliza tu método
```

Comment: Excelente Aporte @Flxtr :D

Answer (score 0):

Tienes toda la lógica en el mismo evento. Como buena practica sepera validaciones, acceso a datos en métodos o clases diferentes. 
Supongo que el evento BtnnoConforme_Click lo estas llamando por ajax desde el cliente, y tambien supongo que el encargado de mostrar el aviso "Se actualizo correctamente" esta en la función Javascript showModal1(). 
En esa función javascript deberias recargar la página o la tabla o el registro que acabas de actualizar.

Comment: amigo le estoy haciendo asi   location.reload(); pero cada rato se actualiza no puedo detener

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo separa la lógica en métodos, colocar todo el código "en la condición del PostBack", por ejemplo, no te va a facilitar tu trabajo.

Por lo que ví en tu pregunta, no pude detectar dónde estás refrescando los datos de tu GridView, por lo tanto, la tabla no muestra los cambios hechos a los datos...

Dicho esto, te sugiero crear primero un método que almacene la lógica que usas para consultar la información de tu base de datos y asignar estos datos a tu GridView.

Ejemplo:

```
private void ConsultarDatos()
{
   try
   {
      // Coloca el código que uses para consultar la información
      // y bindear dicha información en tu GridView.
   }
   catch (ex)
   {
       label1.Text = "Error en el método ConsultarDatos();. Error: " + ex.Message;
   }       
}
```

Luego, en tu método `Page_Load` puedes modificar tu lógica así:

```
private void Page_load()
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      ConsultarDatos();
   }       
}
```

En tu botón *luego de que efectivamente hayas hecho la inserción/actualización de datos*, puedes invocar el método que dibuja los datos en el GridView:

Ejemplo:

```
private void btn_guardarInformacion()
{
   // Toda tu lógica...
   label1.text = "información guardada.";

   // Con este paso, se actualizará los datos 
   // y serán visibles en el GridView.
   ConsultarDatos();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok el problema de que no muestra el campo Validado = SI,

*Supongo que el campo @active que envias al stored es el Validado que muestras en el grid.  De ser esto correcto, te recomiendo lo siguiente:*

1. Revisa el `store` por fuera del sistema, directo en BD `sp_atendertarea`

   Valida que se este haciendo el insert en el campo:

   ```
    md.Parameters["@active"].Value = true;
   ```

   Supongo que aquí es donde estas guardando esa columna del grid.
2. Revisa que después de guardar la información estés consultando los datos del grid otra vez.
3. Checa el mapeo de datos que haces hacia el grid, el mapeo lo haces aqui directo:

   ```
               da.Fill(dt);
               DtgSolicitudes.DataSource = dt;
               DtgSolicitudes.Visible = true;
   ```

Pero si el grid tiene alguna configuración en modo diseño o en otra parte donde estes mapeando los datos, revisa que las columnas se llamen igual que en el dt.

Creo que con esas revisiones ya podrías resolver tu problema.

**NOTA**: De ser posible ¿puedes publicar lo que contiene tu stored?